# Verificar si el campo está vacio o no

Tags: php

Cómo verificar si el campo está vacío o no en (MYSQLi, php 5.6). Acá les dejo mi código:

```
if(isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"])) {
    $message = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["_fullMessage"]);
    $message = strip_tags($message);
    $db->real_query("INSERT INTO profile_wall (page_id, poster_id, message, time) VALUES ('" . $_pageId . "', '" . USER_ID . "', '" . $message . "', '" . time() . "')");
}


<form method='post'>
            <center>
            <textarea name="_fullMessage" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
            </center>
            <br />
            <div align='right'>
                <input class="btblack" type='submit' name='_commentSubmit' value='Comentar'>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Anduve creando un sistema de comentarios, pero aún que no ponga nada en el 'textarea' envía datos a la db; apenas comienzo en PHP perdonen.

Comment: Puedes poner el atributo required a tu textarea, lo que te servirá para no poder hacer un input hasta que haya un valor en el

Comment: Con requiered en html y en php con `trim y isset`

Comment: Tu `isset` está basándose en `_commentSubmit` que siempre tendrá valor, deberías basarlo en `_fullMessage`, ya que es la condición que decide si se inserta o no en la base de datos. Aunque como han comentando más arriba, conviene que le pongas un `required` al textarea, es bueno que valides también del lado del servidor. Te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas, ya que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, y a los demás igual. Utilice este código con `empty`

Comment: CUIDADO con estos temas.

Hay una diferencia muy importante entre isset() y empty()

`isset()` -> verifica que el indice de la variable array esta definido. True si esta definido, false si no lo esta. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

`empty()` -> verifica que el indice de la variable array este definido, y que no sea NULL, o "" (cadena vacia. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Por lo tanto, si tu comprobacion es "que el valor no este vacio", entonces tu comprobacion en PHP debe ser `empty`.

Comment: @Jakala, lo utilice de esta manera: `if(!empty($_POST["_fullMessage"])){`

Comment: En este caso lo más lógico es una verificación con `empty` ya que no creo que se quiera lanzar la inserción en caso de que el valor sea una cadena vacía o algo así. Otra que deberías hacer es implementar consultas preparadas, las cuales son más eficaces que `real_escape_string` contra la *inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 0):

No esta muy clara la duda, para mySQL lo tienes que hacer.

```
where
valor NULL
```

en PHP con el `isset ()`

De todas formas deberias de poner una validacion en cliente de ese texarea.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro lo que quieres conseguir,con esto primero validas que exista la variable y a continuación que no este vacía

```
 if(isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"]&& !empty($_POST["_commentSubmit"))


//empty() devuelve true para un string vacío
$var = "";
var_dump( empty($var) );
```

Como comentan mas arriba si pones required en el campo evitas que llegue vacío

Answer (score 0):

Te corrijo primero unas cosas y te doy las comprobaciones después :D

En un formulario siempre es bueno definir el `action`. Por otro lado el `method` bien sea `POST` o `GET` debe ir en mayúsculas, para evitar sustos.

Te he hecho una comprobación del lado cliente, con jquery, que tendrás que agregar tu librería si no la tienes(te la pego en el código para que te sea mas fácil) y otra en el lado servidor.

Le di una `id` al formulario, para trabajar mas cómodamente con el y use `empty()` en el PHP para poder comprobar, si jquery falla o lo manipulan, que, efectivamente, el `textarea` no es una cadena de texto vacía.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST["_commentSubmit"]) && !empty($_POST['_fullMessage'])) {
        $message = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["_fullMessage"]);
        $message = strip_tags($message);
        $db->real_query("INSERT INTO profile_wall (page_id, poster_id, message, time) VALUES ('" . $_pageId . "', '" . USER_ID . "', '" . $message . "', '" . time() . "')");
    }


?>
<!--esto lo pones en el head-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Se comprueba que el textarea no esté vacio. 
    $('.btblack').click(function(){
        if ($('textarea').val()=="") {
            $('#miform').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Ingresa algún comentario.");
            });
        }
    })
</script>
<form method='POST' id="miform" action="">
            <center>
            <textarea name="_fullMessage" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
            </center>
            <br />
            <div align='right'>
                <input class="btblack" type='submit' name='_commentSubmit' value='Comentar'>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Me cuentas tus dudas. Un saludo.